# How to move div to for next several divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div inside some div.

```
<div id="radnja">
    <div id="movethat"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja">
  </div>
```

I want to move div 'movethat' to next div.
But I want to do that several times depending on how much the random number in H1 is.

```
<div id="kocka">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="baci">
  <h2>Baci kocku</h2>
</div>
```

H1 is random number. I do that with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#baci").click(function() {
var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
$("#kocka h1").text(rand); }); });
```

Help please :)

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID , use class for this

Comment: clear your question what you want to do with `movethat` div?

Comment: Its unclear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I want to move `movethat` div for several divs. Now hi is in first `radnja`. I want to move him for 3 `radnja` divs if H1 shows number 3. If H1 shows number 5, I want to move `movethat` for 5 `radnja` divs etc.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen But if I do that for example i put classes for `radnja` divs: .1 , .2 , .3 , .4... how to move how many times do `h1` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `class` but not `id`, following code is helpful for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#baci").click(function() {
  var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
  for(var i = 0;i<rand;i++){
    $('#movethat').appendTo($('#movethat').parent().next())
  }
  $("#kocka h1").text(rand); }); 
});
```

```css
.radnja {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  float:left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radnja">
    <div id="movethat">222</div>
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  </div>
<div id="kocka">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="baci">
  <h2>Baci kocku</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried, it's working, what does it have error?

Answer (score 0):

First click on `kocka h1` to generate random number and then click on button. `movethat` div will move to another div based on generated random number amount.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#baci").click(function() {
var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
$("#kocka h1").text(rand); }); });

$("#btnMoveDiv").on('click',function(){
  var dv = $("#movethat").parent("div");
  var randNo = $("#kocka h1").text();
  if(randNo <8){
     $("#radnja"+randNo).append(dv.html());
     dv.empty();
     $("#movethat").html("Movethat moved to div : "+ randNo);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radnja">
    <div id="movethat">movethat text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="radnja1">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja2">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja3">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja4">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja5">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja6">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja7">
  </div>
  <div id="radnja8">
  </div>
  
  <div id="kocka">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="baci">
  <h2>Baci kocku</h2>
</div>

<button id="btnMoveDiv">Move movethat div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML cannot have duplicate ID. Change all those ID to class and try the below code. On every click, random number is generated and based on that number, `movethat` is moved in that `div`. You will need to check the output in firebug.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#baci").click(function() {
    var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    $("#kocka h1").text(rand);
    var cloneHtml = $("#movethat").clone();
    $("#movethat").remove();
    $(".radnja").eq(rand).html(cloneHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radnja">
  <div id="movethat">this is moving</div>
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>
<div class="radnja">
</div>

<div id="kocka">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="baci">
  <h2>Baci kocku</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So what should I put in place instead of `radnja`?

Comment: I removed ID and used that as Class.

Answer (score 0):

@Jovan Belanov First of all you can't use same id's multiple time. Instead of id's you can use class name for the same purpose.
Secondly, don't know what you are asking in your question.
Please find following code. I hope you are expecting the same.

```css
.radnja,#kocka,#baci{
float:left;
}

h1,h2{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="radnja">
    <div id="movethat">hi</div>
 </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
    <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
    <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
    <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
    <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
  <div class="radnja">
  hi
  </div>
<div id="kocka">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="baci">
  <h2>Baci kocku</h2>
</div>
 
  </div>
```